# Sharing application in facebook and twitter in android

Tags: android

In my application there is 1 functionality for sharing the my application link from markrt.

But problem is that how could i get the link of my application on android market before

submiting the my application to the market...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very much easy, just look at below link:

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=YourPackageName
```

Where YourPackageName is the name of package of your application.

**FYI, Generally android application is uploaded on market with the package name, which must be unique in any case.**

**For example:**

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facebook.katana , here com.facebook.katana is the main package declared in the AndroidManifest.xml file with **`package`**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebook.katana"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: Hi
So u mean that i shoud give the package name after = sign https://market.android.com/details?id=com.test.myapp
will it work perfectly?????????

Comment: @user1069925 yes obvious, just copy the value of "package" from android manifest xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the android market follows the app link as with what you've mentioned in your android manifest.xml

For Eg.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.company.testing.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" 
   >
```

will be like this. But ensure the package you ve chosen is available in android market.

> https://market.android.com/details?id=com.company.testing.app&hl=en